# How to implement PPP in linux server

Tags: php, networking, network-programming, p2p, network-protocols

This must be vague to ask, but I need a possible solutions. 
I'm working on a project where 10 or more linux (Ubuntu) server need to talk to each other using specific ID. Without using WAN IP or Port forwarding.

1. I've tried with a third party library, they charge 2$ or 3$ per ID. And ask me to establish 3 rely server. I'm okay with it and ready to spend money, but the project will rely on this server completely after implementation, if they discontinue the service later, I will be screwed.
2. So I thought to go for either a reputed P2P service provider or Implementing on my own. But neither could find one who provides nor have an idea of implementing this.

Please help me with it. Give some ideas.

Comment: I bit vague but great question. Maybe it's best suited to ask in http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/